# A fast encryption/decryption algorithm that will NOT be used for security, but to combat spam

Tags: performance, encryption, spam

I am looking for a fast encryption/decryption algorithm to be used against spam.
I don't know enough about this field to try and make my own, and in any case, I understand that it would be a bad idea to use something new, so I need some suggestions.

I have looked around SO and tried google but most of the results were explaining how encryption/decryption is slow in order to be hard to break, which I understand, but there are cases when the data expires rapidly and the secret key(salt?) can change very fast, so a fast algorithm would be very useful.

Comment: How do you plan to use it against spam?

Comment: Can u explain your need a bit more clearer. I don't think you require a encryption algo. Presume, a hashing function should suffice. please clarify.

Comment: @Gian I am working on a website that has a voting system. The website will have every post on the front page, but in order to vote the user must go to the comments section of the page, and to get there they must click a link. The link address will contain an encrypted string with the user IP and the post id, now if the user sends the link to really many people and they all spam the vote button I can detect it, since I now know that they didn't find the post organically.

Now I know this is not the perfect system, but I think I could get it to work, and I don't really have another option.

Comment: @Karthikeyan I can't use hasing because I need to extract some data back, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this article on [block ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_ciphers). Here is how you can make your own cipher:

**Encryption:**

1. Store your own private data, preferably randomly generated for each cipher.
2. Using your private data as a seed in a pseudorandom number generator. Produce a string of bits as long as the data you want to encode, a.k.a. the plaintext. This string of "random" bits is the key.
3. For each bit of the key, take the corresponding bit from the plaintext, which we will call `a` and `b` respectively. The XOR of the two yields the corresponding bit in the ciphertext.
4. Use the ciphertext as you wish.

**Decryption:**

1. Take the ciphertext and retrieve the private data for it.
2. Use the private data as a seed in the same pseudorandom number generator to produce the key from before.
3. Follow the steps above to get the plaintext instead of the ciphertext.

**Example:**

```
// ENCODE
plaintext (in bits)                          = 00100001111110
key (from pseudo-random number generator)    = 10101110110101
ciphertext (XOR each bit)                    = 10001111001011

// DECODE
ciphertext                                   = 10001111001011
key (from pseudo-random number generator)    = 10101110110101
plaintext                                    = 00100001111110
```

Comment: -1. That is just an XOR cipher. If you *ever* reuse the keystream, it all falls apart and everything can be recovered.

Comment: Why? If the attacker does not know the plaintext at all and does not want to spend hours decrypting the message, it should be pretty secure. I was not trying to give the safest algorithm, because that is not what @notok wanted.

Comment: But an XOR cipher with keystream reuse is not any better than double ROT13. If anything, it's worse – it gives a false sense of security.

Comment: Double ROT13 would give the plaintext of a ciphertext. That would only happen if you use the keystream on the same plaintext twice.

Comment: "Double ROT13" is a metaphor. Please see this question if you still don't believe keystream reuse is a bad idea: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse

Comment: Good link. I agree in general. But for this context I am not so worried.

Comment: A false sense of security is always worrying. Is there a reason why a proper cipher like AES is not applicable here? To be honest, I'm not even sure encryption is the correct approach in the first place.

Comment: AES is very secure, but also pretty slow. If encryption is a choice here, it should probably be an algorithm like XXTEA or Blowfish.